# How to access a custom action page

Tags: joomla-2.5, templates

I have never worked on Joomla so I apologize for my naive question.

I have a button on a page which redirects to this URL - https://ttmac.com/en/online-courses/buy?view=order-multiple-courses&catid=6

I can understand we are attaching query strings in the URL which should be captured by online-courses (it's not a page though). Here's where I am confused since I've never worked in Joomla.

I am trying to locate the code that is being generated by 'order-multiple-courses' action but unable to locate the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are new to Joomla, we strongly recommend that you develop on the latest version of it.  Could you perhaps tell us more about what you are actually trying to achieve with this development?

Comment: @mickmackusa I am not developing anything. The company I have recently joined developed the site long ago for their client. It is using the Guru LMS component; however some customized codes have been added to it. The above URL generates a page that displays a form where you can add courses and checkout. I am trying to figure out where that page is coming from because I need to make some changes in there.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Guru LMS component so this is could be just an somewhat educated guess. The view might found in /components/com_{insert guru component name}/views/order-multiple-courses/.  Within that directory you normally get a view.html.php and a /default.php, or any other name, that will make up the page your are seeing. Depending on the changes you need to make one of those two files is mostly where you are going to make it.

Comment: @Irata That was my initial though as well, coming from a Wordpress background, but to my surprise there's no such view in the guru components folder. That is why I'm stumped.

Comment: I don't know Guru LMS but, with similar components the component/com_your-component-name is usually just an entry point. In one component I am familiar with, there is a folder with the same name. What I mean is, if your component is named com_gurulms, I would look for a gurulms folder somewhere. It may be that Guru LMS is a framework of its own with an entirely different way of working.

This is often done so the developer can maintain a single, common code base for both WordPress and Joomla.

Sorry I can't be more helpful. Good luck with your search...

Comment: @SheldonSeale Thanks for the input. I figured it out however. The developer who worked on it initially created a custom template within the Theme, using the Guru components but it was hard to trace back to it. I had to read each line of code to understand where the view was coming from. Anyway, thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out finally. So the developer created a custom template deep within the Theme used for the site. I was expecting a custom component since it was using the GURU LMS but apparently that was not the case.